# Why is the rate of change of velocity with distance not constant?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, free-fall

My physics textbook says, "Galileo concluded that the rate of change of velocity with time is a constant of motion for all objects in free fall. On the other hand, the change in velocity with distance is not constant- it decreases with the increasing distance of fall." How is that possible? Shouldn't the change in velocity of an object increase the greater the distance it falls?

Comment: Two things falling, both are increasing their speed by the same amount *per second*.  But If something were falling slowly, it is speeding more *per meter* than it speeds up *per meter* if it is moving really fast. Because the second object goes far per second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the object is moving faster, it spends less time in a given spot, so its velocity has less time to change per unit distance. This can be made precise with the chain rule: $\frac{dv}{dy} = \frac{dv/dt}{dy/dt} = \frac{g}{v}$ gets smaller if $v$ gets bigger and $g$ stays constant.

Comment: thank you so much!